# How does yield a file-like response from a web server work?

Tags: python, http, webserver, yield

```
while True:
    data = resp.read(65536)
    if not data:
        break
     yield data
```

Actually I'm not asking for code, but the principle of the entire http connection.

If I stop the program at one yield, for instance, debugging, where is the rest of my http response data? Are they still in the server, or in my client machine's memory?

If the former one, what does the program do in web server to prevent the data from being flushed to client all by once? Control the stream by TCP sequence?

Comment: What type is `resp`?  A socket?  Blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it could be urllib2 which provides a file-like object after you use urlopen, or other tools, like Requests library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it depends on your framework. Normally, for yielded responses the [Chunked HTTP Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) is used. So only data, that was read, is sent to the client. No data is buffered at the server side.

Comment: How does the server decide if it's going to use chunked transfer encoding? According to the client's request? Or who on earth makes the decision?

Comment: You decide, by yielding the contents. Nobody knows, how much data there is to come, until your function is finished, but nobody want's to buffer an unknown amount of data.

Comment: A little confused... Any way, I have to write a robust and efficient downloading client base on python and http protocol. One way is to use Range header with multi-thread, the other one is about dealing with file-like reponse with chunked encoding and yield, (probably more memory saving?). Which one do you suggest?

Comment: Anyway, support Ranges, so the client can decide, which data to load, and most clients can restart broken connections.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the length of your data,if your data is short, the client read once and get them all, if you stop the program, your data is in client's memory.Otherwise, if your data is too long to read once, it may still in the server side, at this time, you stop the client program, the rest data is not in your program memory.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: No,it from my engineering experience, if it's not correct, please point out mistakes.

Comment: the comment was not meant as a criticism, it was a genuine question.

Comment: what does the program do in web server to prevent the data from being flushed to client all by once? Control the stream by TCP sequence?

Comment: Because I used to write C programs, I remember that when using the socket, a read operation must block until the other end write? How does the client inform the server in terms of how many bytes to write, this length 65536 is coded in the client's side.